# jquery form validate without submit and with submit possible?

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit

I am using a form that has a lot of validate rules and messages and I am using submitHandler to submit a AjaxSubmit then.

This is OK, if I want to send form on demand which I usually do. But on the same page I'd like to do a validation without submit when user first visits the page, so he can see where the errors are.

Is this possible without reentering all the validation rules and messages again?

Now I am using like:

```
 var v = $("#form").validate({
        errorClass: "dmxError",
        rules: {
            my rules....
        },
        messages: {
            my messages
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);


        }
    });
```

I also have options for ajax which I think are not relevant for what I try to acomplish now ;-)

How do I call validate with same data without submit when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't mean to be rude to the one who helped me, but I think I may found a better solution.

I used: $("#form").valid() and this seems to trigger validation on load without submit. Because if everything is OK I see form is not submitted because there is no "submitted" response that I have, so I have validated it without submit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule on a hidden field that will validate to false, when the page loads. You can use a javascript variable to make the validation change from false to true programmatically.

When you are loading the page, submit the form from your javascript code. The validation will fail and errors, if any, will be reported. Then, in order to allow the user to actually submit the form, make the hidden field rule to validate to true.

Comment: I am not sure if I was clear, I need the page to validate only when loaded and show errors if any. If user presses submit it would validate and submit data.

Comment: This what I also propose. When you load try to submit the form with javascript code. Make sure the validation will fail, by adding a hidden field (an item with 0px height or whatever). The validation will fail and if there are more errors, they will be displayed. Then change the hidden field value so that it passes validation.

Comment: Funny is I don't know how to trigger script onload :-(